# R: read and clean layer with v.clean (using rgrass7)

Tags: r, grass-gis, rgrass7, v.clean

I'm trying to execute some rgrass7 processing from R but I can't even get the first process done. I would like to clean a vector line layer. The goal here is not just to clean the topology, that's collateral, but learning how to execute rgrass7 processes with vector data.

Here is the code that throw error:

```
library(rgrass7)

# PARAMETERS
lpath <- "./Layers/Lines_light/Lines.shp"
l <- readOGR(lpath)

G <- initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass76",
               home = getwd(),
               gisDbase = getwd(),
               location = 'grassdata',
               mapset = "PERMANENT",
               override = TRUE)
G
use_sf()  

# clean (here, in input, I tried l, "l", "lpath", lpath...
execGRASS("v.clean",
          input = "lpath",
          output = 'l_clean',
          tool = 'break',
          flags = 'c')
```

The error:

```
Error in execGRASS("v.clean", input = "lpath", output = "l_clean", tool = "break",  : 
  The command:
v.clean -c input=lpath output=l_clean tool=break
produced an error (1) during execution:
ERROR: El mapa vectorial <lpath> no se ha encontrado
```

By the way, the tool work just perfect from QGIS in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: There you go :-)

Comment: I know nothing about using GRASS inside R but in GRASS you would need to import the shapefile for it to become a "map", try v.import first

Comment: Yes, you are missing the `v.import ` step before doing anything with the map in GRASS GIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @markusN and @BERA comented, I lacked the import part which I did not using `v.import` if not `writeVECT` like this:

```
library(rgrass7)

# PARAMETERS
lpath <- "./Layers/Lines_light/Lines.shp"
l <- readOGR(lpath)

G <- initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass76",
               home = getwd(),
               gisDbase = getwd(),
               location = 'grassdata',
               mapset = "PERMANENT",
               override = TRUE)
G
use_sf()  

# import lines
writeVECT(l, 'l', v.in.ogr_flags = c('o','overwrite','quiet'))

# clean
execGRASS("v.clean",
          input = "l",
          output = 'l_clean',
          tool = 'break',
          flags = 'c')
```